# Representing conditional statements in Alloy Analyzer

Tags: conditional-statements, software-design, alloy, formal-verification

I am trying to represent conditional (if-else) statements using alloy. My understanding is that I need to use Hoare triples. However, I don't have much experience with software verification tools and I can't find any online tutorials that demonstrate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic syntax for conditional statements is *implies*:

```
 cond => expr [ else expr ]
```

You can also use:

```
 cond implies expr [ else expr ]
```

However, make sure you understand the logical rules for implies/=>.

This sounds rather a fundamental program; did you read [Daniel Jackson's book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/software-abstractions-revised-edition)? Did you look at simple examples, for example [in the model repo](https://github.com/AlloyTools/models)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I found out about the book and have been skimming through. Thanks again